# Crystal Reports Formula Summarise Count of Field A that are between Field B and C

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm new to crystal reports and i've watched some videos on basic formulas but i'm not sure how to approach this.

I want a summary count of how many rows where the weight is between the T1 and T2 figure for the given row.

Heres some sample data.

```
Weight    T1       T2
0.236    0.230     0.220
0.227    0.230     0.220
0.232    0.230     0.220
0.231    0.230     0.220
0.238    0.230     0.220
0.221    0.220     0.211
0.212    0.220     0.210
0.231    0.220     0.210
0.218    0.220     0.210
0.221    0.220     0.210
```

Could anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong place, it was a running total I needed to create with 'Use a formula' on evaluate.